# Simple XML: suppress length attribute in serialized arrays

Tags: java, xml-serialization, simple-framework

Take a class member like this one:

```
@ElementArray
private String[] names;
```

Simple XML will serialize this as:

```
<names length="3">
   <string>Jonny Walker</string>
   <string>Jack Daniels</string>
   <string>Jim Beam</string>
</names>
```

Is there any way I can suppress the `length` attribute for the enclosing element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be a straightforward way to do it (see [issue #39](https://github.com/ngallagher/simplexml/issues/39)), but a hack will do the trick: Lists can be inlined (so only the elements for the items will be added, without the enclosing element and its unwanted attribute). You can then add a “pristine” enclosing element with a `@Path` annotation. Arrays cannot be inlined directly, but you can convert them to lists.

- Write a getter which returns the array as a `List`.
- Annotate the getter as `@ElementList(inline=true)` and `@Path("names")`.
- If you have added the `@Default` annotation, annotate the array as `@Transient` so it won’t get serialized twice.

Like this:

```
@Transient
private String[] names;

@ElementList(inline=true)
@Path("names")
public List<String> getNamesAsList() {
    if (names == null)
        return null;
    else
        return Arrays.asList(names);
}
```

Which will then yield:

```
<names>
   <string>Jonny Walker</string>
   <string>Jack Daniels</string>
   <string>Jim Beam</string>
</names>
```

You’ll have to add some extra magic for de-serialization, likely [constructor injection](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#immutable). (Since in my case the array is `final`, I will need that anyway.)

If you require de-serialization, you will need to de-serialize the exact same elements you serialized. That is, `@ElementList(inline=true) @Path("names")` will work whereas e.g. `@ElementList(name="names")` will throw a validation error.